# Gmail App - Lollipop Shared Elements transitions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I know that this question is being asked many times, but still i was not able to find solution.

Well we all know that Lollipop Shared Elements transitions only work with lollipop devices, but the recent update to Gmail app has the same animation effect in pre-lollipop(i guess starting from 4.1).

The same effect is the Yplan app as well.

How to achieve that ? i guess they are using the Shared Elements transitions

Comment: The official API does not provide any automatic "shared element transition" API for devices below Lollipop. Gmail and other apps may be using the approach described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA) to achieve a similar effect though.

Answer (score 1):

You dont get official "shared element transition" API below lollipop so only thing you can do is manually implement it.

1. You can also use this [open source library](https://github.com/rey5137/material).
2. This is second open source library [which works for 2.2+](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this library for activity and fragment transitions for pre lollipop devices

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.albinmathew:PreLollipopTransition:1.1.2'}
```

https://github.com/albinmathew/PreLollipopTransition